# Best option for monitoring the UI while avoiding state

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, functional-programming

I am fairly new to Swift and iOS development. I have learned about, and aspire to, the aim of using functional programming to avoid state. Therefore I am at a stage in my journey where I would like to ask a conceptual question about programming techniques for achieving this.

Say I have a regular UISwitch on a regular UIView which is controlled by a regular UIViewController. Several methods within the ViewController class depend on the value of the UISwitch to dictate their precise action.

I started by checking the value of the UISwitch within each method as needed, but that resulted in warnings when those methods are called asynchronously on a background thread. I knew I couldn't make changes to the UI on a background thread, but it seems I can't check it's state either.

So I resorted to the old favourite - the class property - to store the current state of the switch, but it feels like I'm going against the fundamental principle of functional programming in doing this.

Then, I realised that to allow the switch to remain as the user left it after the app is closed, I needed to write its setting into UserDefaults. So I can get the value from UserDefaults every time I need it, but my concern here is that this approach my be considerably slower given the need for iOS to go back and forth to UserDefaults.

So, my question is this: what is the best/fastest/least-likely-to-cause-me-future-problems way of getting that UISwitch setting within my ViewController's methods?

1. Check the UI by dispatching to the main thread every time the switch needs to be checked
2. Store the value in a class property, and hang the consequences
3. Get the value from UserDefaults every time it's needed
   or
4. Any other approach I haven't learned about yet

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's better UX to persist important user choices somewhere. You shouldn't be worried about using `UserDefaults` though - it's designed to be used for storing those simple key value settings. Also, it's not using physical memory i/o after you load it for the first time - you need to call `.synchronize` for it to happen (for example when the app goes to the background).

I suggest 2 approaches:

The first more beginner-friendly approach would be setting up a variable like this:

```
var yourFlag : Bool {
    get {
        let defaults = Defaults.standard
        return defaults.bool(forKey: "yourFlagKey") 
    }

    set (newValue) {
        let defaults = Defaults.standard
        defaults.set(newValue, forKey: "yourFlagKey")
    }
}
```

This way you could just use your variable like any other instance variables, but under the hood it would use `UserDefaults`. For example, in your switch value change action your could simply set the new value and it would persist to `UserDefaults`:

```
func onValueChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
   yourFlag = !sender.on
}
```

I'd suggest not storing this variable in your ViewController though. I usually make a container class for all of my user settings so I can check them anywhere I need them. Ideally you'd want to inject this container as a dependency for your `UIViewController`.

The second approach (if you truly want to go deeper into functional programming) would be learning how to use a FRP (functional reactive programming) framework like RxSwift and treating value change event as an observable you can build your processes on. However, if you're just starting out, I'd suggest learning doing stuff the regular (apple) way so you know what benefits and drawbacks FRP brings.

Answer (score 0):

The way I recommend is to have a `Bool` property for keeping the state of Switch object. Update it anytime the Switch Control's state changes.

Any of those methods should access the `Bool` property, not the Switch Control's state directly.

Using UserDefaults for a couple of Settings that need to persist is fine. I'd recommend to load the initial value for the Switch Control from User Defaults inside `viewDidLoad()` but set the most up-to-date value whenever the View Controller is about to disappear or the App itself goes into background or is about to get destroyed, because User Defaults uses a `.plist` under the hood and any operation may take longer than expected, and sometimes that may cause unexpected behaviors.

Also, you could use a `SettingStateController` class containing that `Bool` property and other things. Let it initialize all properties from User Defaults inside the initializer and save them to User Default when its instance gets deallocated. That way, the access will be faster, and code will be separated based on different concerns. A `View Controller` should behave more like a view, the responsibility of deciding to use User Default, a local file, Core Data etc. should be achieved in a separate class, as advised above.